# How to log errors in python script (process)

Tags: python, logging

I need to log errors in python script which running as process.

My current code:

```
import ips
import sys
import time
import logging
import os
import string
import json
import multiprocessing
import MySQLdb as mdb

from daemon import Daemon


logging.basicConfig(format = u'%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s] %(message)s', level = logging.INFO, filename = u'/var/log/info.log')


class MyDaemon(Daemon):
    def run(self):        
        print 'the script was run'
        logging.info("the script was run")

        while True:

            [My code Here]

            time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    daemon = MyDaemon('/var/run/pid.pid')
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.start()
        elif 'stop' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.stop()
        elif 'restart' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.restart()
        else:
            print "Unknown command"
            sys.exit(2)
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print "usage: %s start|stop|restart" % sys.argv[0]
        sys.exit(2)
```

Some times my process shutdown but I doesn't see error report. How I can see error report if process shutdown?

Comment: If it's shutting down with a exception, you'll want to have a catch-all `try` in your main

Comment: I would advise that you move the `basicConfig()` call into the `if __name__ == '__main__'` body - though that is not your problem (and why this is a comment, not an answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use the logging module to capture an exception. E.g.:

```
import logging

except serial.SerialException as e:
      logging.debug("Could not open serial port: {}".format(com_port, e))
```

I don't know your code, you enter in the loop but I can advise you to use maybe returns in program. If it breaks for a specific reason, then you get some hints. This can be logged too.
In python you easily can return several parameters. I don't know, why you don't use these features.